# Angular 2 Material Input change placeholder dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, placeholder

I want to change the text of the input placeholder dynamically.
The console.log already gives the updated string but the interface doesn't update so there stays the old placeholder.
How can I get the Interface to recognize the change?

```
document.getElementById(this.implicKey).setAttribute('placeholder', options[i].implication);

console.log(document.getElementById(this.implicKey).getAttribute('placeholder'));
```

Comment: why are you using document.getElementById you can change using binding

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you can change your input placeholder  dynamically like this

```
<md-input-container class="demo-full-width">
                <input mdInput [(ngModel)]="firstname" placeholder="{{somePlaceholder}}" name="firstname" required>
                <md-error>This field is required</md-error>
            </md-input-container>
```

component.ts

```
somePlaceholder : string = "new value";
```

now you can change  somePlaceholder value any where in the class.

Comment: I added this function setPlaceholder(value: string) { this.somePlaceholder = value; } and passed it as a closure to my service so I can set the placeholder when data arrives. But it says this is undefined. What am I doing wrong? The service's subscribe happens inside the service class itself and I invoke the closure method onSuccess.

Answer (score 5):

We can do that using property binding.

In the HTML, use square brackets:

```
<input formControlName="events" type="text" [placeholder]="newPlaceHolder">
```

In your typescript file, define the property:

```
newPlaceHolder: string = "original place holder";
```

Then, change the property value:

```
newPlaceHolder= "my new place holder";
```

Answer (score 1):

another option may be in the HTML, use square brackets whith [attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding):

```
<input formControlName="events" type="text" [attr.placeholder]="newPlaceHolder">
```

In your typescript file, define the property:

```
newPlaceHolder: string = "text binding"
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works great for me:

(I use it to show dynamic error on mat-autocomplete form field)

on your HTML:

```
 [placeholder]="isPlaceHolderShowError('myFormControlName')"
```

on your TS:

```
    isPlaceHolderShowError(myFormControlName) {
    if (this.form.controls[myFormControlName].invalid && this.form.controls[myFormControlName].touched) {
      return 'this is my error text'
    }
    return 'this is the initial placehloder'
  }
```